# How to align div tags vertically in a mobile device and horizontally on larger screens in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three div tags, 1 parent and 2 child. The parent div should take up full width of the page and height of the content (i.e. the 2 child divs). The 2 child divs should be positioned horizontally on bigger screens (i.e.) laptops, desktops...) and occupy 50% of the width of parent and expand as per content.

The 2 child divs should align/stack vertically on smaller devices (i.e. mobile), taking up full width of the parent and expand as per of content.

I have tried playing around with the display properties including block, inline-block and position absolute and relative with no luck.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.child2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: you ccan use a viewport or a media query

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-design).

Answer (score 2):

`flex` and `grid` can let you drop the mediaquerie breaking point.

With a mediaquerie, you can switch back to `display:block;`

For infos : Since you use flex on the parent, display value on the children will have no effects but width:50% can be too much if margins, padding or borders are involved. box-sizing can be your friend here.With flex, you can use `flex:1;` to spray evenly the children , no matter the number, borders, padding or margin.

examples with grid, flex and a switch back to block via a mediaquerie .*breakpoint is set at around 620px in the demo , update the value(s). used to fit your needs*.

```css
/* the flex container without mediaquerie */

div[class] {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 20vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* needed to stack children once to big */
}

div[class] div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 300px;
  /* 2 children + margin and borders makes a break point at around 620px */
  background: lightblue;
}

div div {
  border: solid;
  margin: 3px;
  background: tomato;
}

div[id] {
  min-height: 20vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  /* again a break point at about 620px when 2 children no need of mediaquerie */
}

div[id][class] div {
  background: lightgreen;
}


/* remove the grid system at about 620px */

@media screen and (max-width: 621px) {
  div[id],
  div[class] {
    min-height: 30vh;
    /* has a meaning with a grid system */
  }
  div[id][class] {
    display: block;
    /* looses the grid system, back to classic layout see min-height behavior not resizing  children */
    border: solid;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
<div id>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
<div id class>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

a few usefull links:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1):

Try using css grid styling to do this. This is a sample code where the child1 and child2 are in the same row in a large screen but when the screen becomes smaller (mobile view) it will be one below the other. Hope it helps you

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    child1
  </div>
  <div>
    child2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the child2 div disappear on small screens and on larger the content is not occupying the full width.

Comment: Oh yes i forgot to remove the width that was fixed to the divs. I have updated the code. Check and see if it helps your problem

Comment: Still the same issue, could it be because I am using display: inline-block for child1 and child2 divs.

Comment: Could be the problem, do not have and display or width styles on your child divs

Answer (score 1):

Use a `media query` at the moment you want to break down the two child divs to occupy 50% of the width:

> **Media queries** are useful when you want to modify your site or app depending on a device's general type (such as print vs. screen) or specific characteristics and parameters (such as screen resolution or browser viewport width).

[MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
// Add your styling here.
}
```

See below example for the code.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    display: flex;
  }
  .child {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

// Color styling
.parent {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.child {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.child:last-child {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime reprehenderit modi corporis veritatis iste sit, numquam hic velit dolorem recusandae commodi blanditiis animi quisquam temporibus illum id, repellat saepe adipisci eos odit obcaecati atque?
    Nihil expedita ab doloribus cum, iusto suscipit autem quos tempore officiis nesciunt maiores. Quos, labore eum perferendis cupiditate veritatis excepturi, tenetur quasi perspiciatis eius suscipit distinctio inventore adipisci asperiores incidunt numquam
    fugiat autem minus quae. Possimus fugiat eos consequuntur iusto et nisi earum obcaecati qui accusantium tenetur totam animi debitis minima accusamus cum quas, amet architecto quam sequi quisquam eum dolorum exercitationem rerum adipisci, esse! Voluptates.</div>
  <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, enim reprehenderit asperiores sapiente blanditiis odit. Possimus vel porro in eligendi vitae officiis placeat odit asperiores illo consequatur, quos enim nam quam natus pariatur,
    sed autem excepturi temporibus, consequuntur beatae eos. Exercitationem voluptatum, aliquam harum delectus provident laudantium perferendis atque aliquid!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child {
  max-width: 98%;
  flex: 0 0 98%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 0 1% 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
.child {
  max-width: 48%;
  flex: 0 0 48%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

`